# Unwrap each face individually into UV 0-1 using Geometry Nodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates

Is it possible to unwrap each individual face of a mesh into the 0 - 1 range using Geometry nodes?

It would be aiming to achieve the same result as the "Reset" UV in the UV unwrapping window.

This way each face of the mesh should show the entire texture.

Is this possible?

[image]